# I have my array as arr=[1,2,3,4]. I pushed an element in it arr.push(5). Now I need to display my array as [5,4,3,2,1]. Any Idea?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array as:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4]

//Push and element to array
arr.push(5)

//Now, arr = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

I need to display my array as

```
Elements in array arr is:
5,1,2,3,4
```

Arr.reverse() gives me
    5,4,3,2,1.
But i need 
    5,1,2,3,4

Comment: so, where is problem?

Comment: [`Array.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse)

Comment: Array.reverse() gives me [5,4,3,2,1]. I needed [5,1,2,3,4]. Arr.reverse() won't help.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use `Array.prototype.reverse()`:

```
console.log(arr.reverse());
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse).

Comment: Array.reverse() gives me [5,4,3,2,1]. I needed [5,1,2,3,4]. Arr.reverse() won't help

Answer (score 0):

This is the code you need to use :

```
arr.reverse();
```

Here is the w3school : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_reverse.asp

Comment: I think you didn't understand the question. arr.reverse() gives me [5,4,3,2,1]. I need [5, 1,2,3,4] and for generalised condition.